# MAMP (mysql) over LAN

Tags: sql-server, mamp

I have found some posts which explain how to setup mysql in MAMP for lan use. Each explanation describe that my.cf needs to be changed so the bind-adress is set to lan ip or 0.0.0.0 which is preferred.

The strange thing is that when i do so, after starting MAMP again, it changes bind-adress back to 127.0.0.1.

I really need to set up a mysql for lan usage, so all team members will be working towards same DB.
Anyone know a good way och a working way in MAMP ?

### Solution

So ive found a solution and here are steps i took on OS X 10.6:

Scenario: My local Mamp setup (computer 1) needs to access Mamps mySQL server over lan on computer 2. All changes mentioned below are made on the remote server, that means computer 2.

1. Mamp File-menu > Edit template... > MySQL my.cnf
2. Make the change to bind adress:
   `# The MySQL server

   [mysqld]

   port = 3306

   socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

   key_buffer = 16M

   max_allowed_packet = 1M

   table_cache = 64

   sort_buffer_size = 512K

   net_buffer_length = 8K

   read_buffer_size = 256K

   read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K

   myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

   bind-address=0.0.0.0`
3. Save ***my.cnf*** and close the editor
4. Now open terminal and type: ***netstat -an | grep 3306*** and you should see something like this:
   **tcp4 0 0 *.3306  *.* LISTEN**
   If you now try to connect (eg. your local WordPress to the remote mySQL server then you probably end up with some error because of user privileges)
5. Add new user to the remote mySQL-server. Head now over to your phpMyAdmin page on the remote computer via Mamp WebStart button and click on **Privileges**. Fill out the textfields, skip **Database for user** and check for all checkboxes in **Global privileges** EXCEPT *Administration* cause those are not needed OR what privileges you want this user to have. When done, hit **OK** at the bottom

*(Note: as host, while creating new user in mysql server leave it empty if you want all users in same LAN to access that particular sql account)*

Now, you should be ok to run. Head back to your own mac (computer 1) and if you are using this for WP development, edit your *wp-config.php* and fill in host as lan-ip, user and pass as you just entered in remote (computer 2) server

[image: demo screenshot]

Comment: Not a question about programming, but about server and service management. Voting to close and move to serverfault.

Comment: And hint: if it changes the bind-address, it might be reading another configuration file somewhere. Monitor MySQL to see what files it accesses.

Comment: I found i Mamp File-menu the right option for my.cf file editing. In there is tried bind adress with both LAN ip and 0.0.0.0 and also changed in WP-config the db adress to lan ip but still didnt want to connect. I also checked for if 3306 is being listened and everything seems ok. I guess its something with the user account... :S ?

Comment: Another thing: when you have answered your own issue you generally post the answer in the answer area instead of just modifying the question.  You can accept your own answer after a day or two.

Comment: Could not find the answer area